# How to close ContentDialog on "Enter" in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I've been trying to get a simple `ContentDialog` with a `TextBox` to close when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the `TextBox`. Sadly it doesn't even work without a `TextBox`, even though the ContentDialog responds to <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

I was hoping there was a way to set a Result from inside the `KeyDown` Handler of the `TextBox`, but it seems `ContentDialog` lacks this?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can close the ContentDialog using `Hide()` method in `TextBox` `KeyDown` handler, simple example:

```
ContentDialog c = new ContentDialog();

var tb = new TextBox();

tb.KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
{
     if (args.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
          c.Hide();
     }
};

c.Content = tb;
c.ShowAsync();
```

**EDIT:**
But it seems to be more complicated when you want to close the dialog without `TextBox`. You have to subscribe on global `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event:

```
ContentDialog c = new ContentDialog();

Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
{
      if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Enter)
      {
            c.Hide();
      }
};
c.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: thanks, that does indeed work. I wonder though why `Hide` doesn't take a parameter to set the `ContentDialogResult` of `ShowAsync` to something different than `ContentDialogResult.None`

Comment: A possible improvement right before the c.Hide() would be to set c.tag = ContentDialogResult.Primary.  For VirtualKey.Escape, set c.tag = ContentDialogResult.Secondary.  If the result of c.ShowAsync is ContentDialogResult.None, then the result can be inferred to be the dialog's tag cast as a ContentDialogResult.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my final solution that would get me a `ContentDialogResult.Primary` on <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I added this to my ContentDialog:

```
    public new IAsyncOperation<ContentDialogResult> ShowAsync()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ContentDialogResult>();

        CaptionTB.KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Key != VirtualKey.Enter) return;
            tcs.TrySetResult(ContentDialogResult.Primary);
            Hide();
            args.Handled=true;
        };

        var asyncOperation = base.ShowAsync();
        asyncOperation.AsTask().ContinueWith(task => tcs.TrySetResult(task.Result));
        return tcs.Task.AsAsyncOperation();
    }
```

unfortunately `ShowAsync` isn't virtual so I had to `new` the function. It works well for me though!

Comment: awesome, you're a genius!

Comment: CaptionTB is not recognized by VS and there is no suggestion for an using... How to fix?

Comment: that's the **T**ext**B**ox I was using for a **Caption**. You'll define that in the XAML as `<TextBox Name="CaptionTB" />`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it isn't (cleanly) possible without workarounds and hacks that will preserve the functionality of identifying which button was pressed. The long answer is that it's fortunately very clean and easy to subclass `ContentDialog` to do exactly what we want:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace NeoSmart.Dialogs
{
    class HotkeyContentDialog : ContentDialog
    {
        public new event TypedEventHandler<ContentDialog, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs> PrimaryButtonClick;
        public new event TypedEventHandler<ContentDialog, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs> SecondaryButtonClick;

        public ContentDialogResult Result { get; set; }
        public new async Task<ContentDialogResult> ShowAsync()
        {
            var baseResult = await base.ShowAsync();
            if (baseResult == ContentDialogResult.None)
            {
                return Result;
            }
            return baseResult;
        }

        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
                Result = ContentDialogResult.Primary;
                PrimaryButtonClick?.Invoke(this, default(ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs));
                Hide();
            }
            else if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape)
            {
                Result = ContentDialogResult.Secondary;
                SecondaryButtonClick?.Invoke(this, default(ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs));
                Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnKeyUp(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just use `HotkeyContentDialog` instead of `ContentDialog` and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since this question has been asked, but a ContentDialog has a DefaultButton property that handles Enter in the way you want.

[ContentDialog.DefaultButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.defaultbutton)

For a TextBox, I assume you have to set the AcceptsReturn property to false because this may interfere with the Enter that is intended to close the dialog.

[TextBox.AcceptsReturn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.acceptsreturn)

Answer (score 0):

Mahmouds solution is more than perfect! Should be accepted as answer IMO. Here is the further reworked HotkeyContentDialog class from me:

```
public class HotkeyContentDialog : ContentDialog
{
    public new event TypedEventHandler<ContentDialog, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs> PrimaryButtonClick;
    public new event TypedEventHandler<ContentDialog, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs> SecondaryButtonClick;
    public ContentDialogResult Result { get; set; }

    public new async Task<ContentDialogResult> ShowAsync()
    {
        var baseResult = await base.ShowAsync();
        return baseResult == ContentDialogResult.None ? Result : baseResult;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter:
                Result = ContentDialogResult.Primary;
                PrimaryButtonClick?.Invoke(this, default);
                Hide();
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape:
                Result = ContentDialogResult.Secondary;
                SecondaryButtonClick?.Invoke(this, default);
                Hide();
                break;
            default:
                base.OnKeyUp(e);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mahmouds solution is not _more than perfect_ . It still *new* 's the function and what's more: it alters the `ShowAsync` signature. If it does that, then why not use an entirely different name? Anyways, your answer has the `switch` change, Mahmouds answer is basically just my answer, a little reworked and more fluff added. If anything I'd accept my answer, but @marcinax note to use the `Hide` method is what made me accept his answer, because that's the core solution to the problem.